# how does systemd activate encrypted swap file on alternate partition?

Tags: linux, systemd, encryption, swap

I have 2 partitions: `/` and `/data`. My swap file is encrypted at `/data/swap`.

So `/etc/crypttab` looks like:

```
root_crypt UUID=6666 none luks
swap /data/swap /dev/urandom swap
```

And `/etc/fstab` looks like (simplified):

```
UUID=abcd1234 / ext4 defaults 0 1
UUID=5678aaaa /data ext4 defaults 0 2
/dev/mapper/swap swap swap defaults 0 2
```

How does systemd possibly handle this? The generated crypttab units have to run before fstab to get `/` to mount, but fstab mounting has to run before crypttab units to get to the encrypted swap file.

Conversely, if I wanted my own systemd unit to find and mount `/data` and then turn on the swap, at what phase would I do it?

EDIT:
Even better, I would like to write my own unit that checks if the swapfile exists and if not, creates it. The script to do that is easy, but what are my `Before` `After` `Wants` and `WantedBy` rules? This is before cryptmount, because the swapfile is encrypted, but it is after, because `/` needs to be mounted first.

It is both before fstab, because the swapfile needs to be created to be used, but it is after, because the swapfile is on a filesystem that must be mounted.

Completely confused.

Comment: Sure, thanks. Not that G+ is showing me an easy way to communicate. Sigh. I am at avi [at] atomicinc [dot] com.