# Convert SysV init run level S to Systemd *.target (Debian)

Tags: systemd, sysvinit, runlevel

I am converting a SysV init style file to Systemd Unit file and it's init section block looks like  this:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ifcheck 
# Required-Start:    $local_fs 
# Required-Stop:
# Should-Start:
# Should-Stop:
# Default-Start:     S
# Default-Stop:      
# Short-Description: Network interfaces check & replace
# Description:       Checks if the interfaces were corrupted or if the special section is missing. If so, a default version will be copied over.
### END INIT INFO
```

I know that run levels 0-6 correspond to various systemd targets:

```
╔══════════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ Run Level (SysVinit) ║  Systemd Target   ║
╠══════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
│ Run level 0          │ poweroff.target   │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Run level 1          │ rescue.target     │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Run level 2          │ multi-user.target │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Run level 3          │ multi-user.target │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Run level 4          │ multi-user.target │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Run level 5          │ graphical.target  │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Run level 6          │ reboot.target     │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Emergency            │ emergency.target  │
└──────────────────────┴───────────────────┘
(According to https://www.tecmint.com/change-runlevels-targets-in-systemd/ )
```

But I have never seen `S` as a run level before. I've seen [some definitions that says it is for single-user](https://wiki.debian.org/RunLevel) while [there are others that define it as a synonym for other run levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel#Ubuntu) and still [others don't have a conclusive defintion](https://serverfault.com/questions/290493/what-is-runlevel-s-on-debian-ubuntu-for).

I know the version I am working with is most likely the **Linux Standard Base specification** because immediately after the init info block is the sourcing of the **lsb init functions** (Sourced via `. /lib/lsb/init-functions`). Also the system is running Debian 8 Jessie.

**What target should I put in the equivalent systemd unit file for run level `S`?**

Comment: Your first link says that it’s for single-user mode, not shutdown.

Comment: Haha, you're right. I just saw "`Runlevels 0, 6 and S are reserved for shutdown,`" and stopped reading there because my brain said "Oh, `S` for shutdown. Makes sense". I'll edit accordingly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`S` has no direct correspondence in systemd.  The `systemd-sysv-generator` program does not handle such van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts.

Debian *used to have* a patched version of that program that wrapped a `rc` script that used `S` inside a service unit with no default dependencies and that was wanted-by `sysinit.target`.  This was imperfect, but then *all* of the operation of `systemd-sysv-generator` is imperfect, because there is no one-size-fits-all mechanistic way to translate van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts.

The Debian systemd people did away with the patch back in July 2016, when they believed that all of the van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts in Debian that used `S` had been superseded with proper service units.  Yours appears to be home grown.

In this case, you are better off completely forgetting about the `S` run-level.  My educated guess, based upon no more than the description, is that what you really should be making is a service unit that is:

```
DefaultDependencies=no
After=local-fs.target
Before=network-pre.target
Wants=network-pre.target
```

and that is `Wanted-By` something suitable, possibly `basic.target`.

Depending from what your service actually does, that ordering after `local-fs.target` may well be overkill.  But that's something only you can determine.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/239978/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394238/5132
- [Why do most systemd examples contain WantedBy=multi-user.target?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/506347/5132)